# Is 27 lands good in a Commander deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

My deck is a ramp deck. It has a lot of creatures under 3 Mana. It is a mono green deck with elves and hydras.

Comment: 27 lands is VERY light for commander, only slightly over 1/4 of the deck.

Comment: It is, but it could be manageable if the deck has low curve and plenty of mana creatures or artifacts. Wouldn't go lower, though.